# From NFA to DFA (basics)

Tags: finite-automata

I am trying to learn NFA to DFA.

This is the original image
[image: NFA]

To begin the process of converting to DFA, I started off with the start state and noticed that if the input is a 1, this means it goes to qb, which would be represented as {qa qb}. I also think it would loop onto itself because if you have a 0 and are in that state, it goes back to qa (does this make sense)?

Now, for the accept state, do I label {qa qb} as an accept state? Needless to say I'm getting myself a little confused... Pardon also the awful handwriting.
[image: my attempt so far]

Comment: "I started off with the start state and noticed that if the input is a 1, this means it goes to $q_b$" No, it means either stay in $q_a$ or go to t$q_b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

`{qa,qb}` will be an accepting state.

Because you are still learning it, you might find these useful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IE4LcyIfGOk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMfLTfoJUAI

(P.S - I don't think you should be asking this kind of elementary questions here, as you are supposed to learn these things from your respective course teacher(s) (Unless you are not studying CS / related subjects, or it is not possible for you to be in touch with someone enough knowledgeable on these subjects). Moreover, you should practice these things a lot to have a clear conception on the conversion process. You should be able to find the basic instructions and procedures for these problems in the internet easily.)